# User defined function to combine CUDF dataframe columns

Tags: pandas, rapids, cudf

As per the title, I am trying to combine the row values from different `cudf.DataFrame` columns. The following code works for a standard `pandas.DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3], 'd': [4]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

def f(row):
    return {'dictfromcolumns': [row['a'], row['b'], row['c'], row['d']]}

df['new'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

The equivalent code with cudf, should look like:

```
dfgpu = cudf.DataFrame(df)
dfgpu['new'] = dfgpu.apply(f, axis=1)
```

But this will throw the following `ValueError` exception:

```py
ValueError: user defined function compilation failed.
```

Is there an alternative way to accomplish the combination of cudf columns (in my case I need to create a dict and store it as the value in a new column)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas allows storing arbitrary data structures inside columns (such as a dictionary of lists, in your case). cuDF does not. However, cuDF [provides an explicit data type](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/nightly/user_guide/data-types.html) called `struct`, which is common in big data processing engines and may be want you want in this case.

Your UDF is failing because Numba.cuda doesn't understand the dictionary/list data structures.

The best way to do this is to first collect your data into a single column as a list (cuDF also provides an explicit `list` data type). You can do this by melting your data from wide to long (and adding a key column to keep track of the original rows) and then doing a groupby `collect` operation. Then, create the struct column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import cudf
import numpy as np

data = {'a': [1, 10], 'b': [2, 11], 'c': [3, 12], 'd': [4, 13]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

gdf = cudf.from_pandas(df)
gdf["key"] = np.arange(len(gdf))

melted = gdf.melt(id_vars=["key"], value_name="struct_key_name") # wide to long format
gdf["new"] = melted.groupby("key").collect()[["struct_key_name"]].to_struct()
gdf
    a   b   c   d   key     new
0   1   2   3   4   0   {'struct_key_name': [1, 4, 2, 3]}
1   10  11  12  13  1   {'struct_key_name': [10, 13, 11, 12]}
```

Note that the struct column in cuDF is not the same as "a dictionary in a column". It's a much more efficient, explicit type meant for storing and manipulating columnar {key : value} data. cuDF provides a "struct accessor" to manipulate structs, which you can access at `df[col].struct.XXX`. It currently supports selecting individual fields (keys) and the explode operation. You can also carry structs around in other operations (including I/O).

Comment: building on top of this question, how to run a `gdf.groupby("column".agg({'field': list}))` when the field is of type `cudf.struct`? - I've tried, trying to aggregate on the "new" field - I got the following exception:  `DataError: All requested aggregations are unsupported.` is there any alternative way to do the same? I can open a new SO Q. if needed.